# Update SQL Server nvarchar(max) field does nothing

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, nvarchar

I'm trying to update a NVARCHAR(MAX) field in SQL Server from PHP. I cannot alter the table and use another type of VARCHAR.

If I try to update with a simple Hello, no errors but nothing is updated.

These are some statements I tried, all of them with same results:

```
UPDATE table SET field='Hello' WHERE id='id'

UPDATE table SET field=CAST('Hello' as NVARCHAR(MAX)) WHERE id='id'

UPDATE table SET field=CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),'Hello') WHERE id='id'

SELECT REPLACE(field,'','Hello') FROM table WHERE id='id'

DECLARE @obs NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @obs=field FROM table WHERE id='id'
SET @obs='Hello'+@obs
UPDATE table SET field=@obs WHERE id='id'

UPDATE table SET field='Hello' WHERE id='id'
UPDATE table SET field.write('Hello',0,len(field)) WHERE id='id'
```

I'm a MySQL user so I don´t know exactly how SQL server works, but this is the only problem I have. The other one was to get values from a  nvarchar(max) field, but I got this with:

```
SELECT cast(field as text) as field FROM table WHERE id='id'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure that the condition `WHERE id='id'` matches any record?

Comment: i dont get how your  id column become become 'id' instead of an integer value. can u post table data?

Comment: You should not take an nvarchar(max) and cast it to text. The text datatype has been deprecated since sql server 2005 in favor of nvarchar(max). And since you cast it to an ascii datatype you would lose any unicode values because it would have been ntext. But just don't do that, keep it as nvarchar(max).

Comment: Rahul, sorry for the id, is just an example. I can update any of the fields in the table except this one, so is not a problem with where condition. Sean Lange, thanks for the info.

Comment: The first statement you give should work perfectly, assuming your table isn't really named "table", and assuming the WHERE condition is valid.  Can you use SQL Server Profiler to see the actual command being sent to SQL Server?  Is it possible that it worked, but that your program can't read the result? Can you use Management Studio or some other tool to directly query the table?

Comment: Hi David. Thank you for your answer, I can´t believe it but I've never seen on this before. As you said, the first statement work perfectly, and the problem was when I was trying to read the value, as in the cast example. Thanks for your advice :-)